# Resizing a plot in Shiny to a fixed size (CSS)

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny dashboard with multiple pages. I cannot get the plot to resize.  With the height: 900px the area changes size but the chart does not resize. It only fills half the height. Anyway to change size?

```
pc_melt <- melt(subset(principal_components$rotation[,c(1:8)]))
groups_for_bar <- as.factor(ifelse(principal_components$rotation>0, 1, 0))

fluidPage(
  tags$div(
    renderPlot({
      ggplot(data = pc_melt, aes(x = Var1, y = value, fill = value)) + 
        geom_bar(colour="black", stat = "identity", width=0.7, position = "dodge") + 
        scale_fill_gradient2(name = "Correlation", 
                            midpoint = 0, 
                            low = "#29115AFF", 
                            high =  "#D6456CFF", 
                            limits = c(-0.6, 0.9)) + 
        theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 9, angle = 45, hjust = 1)) +
        facet_wrap(~ Var2, scales="free")
}), style = "height: 960px; width: 960px"))
```

I tried the height:900px and it does change the size of the area but the chart stays the same.

Comment: Have you tried setting the width and height in the [`renderPlot` function](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/renderPlot.html)?

Comment: That is what I ended up doing this at the end of the plot: 

` }, width = 900, height = 600, res = 72) `